# Angular 6 App not working in IE11 when Dev Tools is close

Tags: .net-core, angular6, ie11-developer-tools

I have read about this issue on some previous thread, however it is still not working, I have commented all console.log and still not working.

I am using Angular 6, may Web API is in .NET Core.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after googling and trying different methods.
It may be a duplicated concern / issue, but I just want to share my experience doing a WebAPI using .Net Core.

I found out that my web app seems to disabled back and forward caching. (can be seen on Console F12 Dev Tools)

*DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337*

Add app.UseResponseCaching(); in Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Use Cross origin resource sharing
        app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
        );

        app.UseAuthentication();
        //20180830
        app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Add services.AddResponseCaching(); in Startup.cs, ConfigureServices.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        ...............

    }
```

Finally add a response header on my Web API solves the issue.

```
    [HttpGet("usraccessbk"), ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, 
            NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult GetWorkXXXXAccess(string user, string buXXXX) {
             ...........
    }
```